# Symfony Production Mode Error Reports and POST values

Tags: php, symfony, error-handling, production

I'm using Symfony 4 but I expect this is much the same for 2 and 3 too.

Production Mode error reports from the swift monolog handler return the complete request URL for GET requests, so it's fairly easy to reproduce the error in development.

But, if it's a POST request, you're in trouble as no POST values are provided.

I've had a dig around in the error handling and logging components but nothing is immediately obvious.

Has anyone else come across this problem and found a fix for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a comment from [@Puya Sarmidani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5297281/puya-sarmidani)... this is what I did in the end:

config/services.yaml:

```
App\Services\MonologExtraProcessor:
    tags:
        - { name: monolog.processor }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

src/Services/MonologExtraProcessor.php:

```
namespace App\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class MonologExtraProcessor
{
    private $postParams = null;

    public function __invoke(array $record)
    {
        if ($this->postParams !== null) {
            $record['extra']['postParams'] = $this->postParams;
        }
        return $record;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $postParams = $event->getRequest()->request->all();
        $this->postParams = empty($postParams) ? null : serialize($postParams);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes i use a fix for this kind of problems that are hard to trace.
You could enable the monolog swift handler in your `config_prod.yml` or */config/packages/prod/monolog.yaml* for symfony 4. This way you'll receive an email same as in dev mode when a error occurs. (depends on the action_level).

See the code below for symfony 4 *(you first need to install monolog)*

```
    monolog:
      handlers:
        main:
          type:         fingers_crossed
          # 500 errors are logged at the critical level
          action_level: critical
          # to also log 400 level errors (but not 404's):
          # action_level: error
          # excluded_404s:
          #     - ^/
          handler:      deduplicated
        deduplicated:
          type:    deduplication
          handler: swift
        swift:
          type:       swift_mailer
          from_email: '**FROM EMAIL**'
          to_email:   '**TO EMAIL**'
          # or list of recipients
          # to_email:   ['dev1@example.com', 'dev2@example.com', ...]
          subject:    'An Error Occurred! %%message%%'
          level:      debug
          formatter:  monolog.formatter.html
          content_type: text/html
```

Comment: This is exactly the config we use. Perhaps I didn't state my question clearly enough... the problem is that the Swift Handler doesn't include POST data in it's error reports.

Comment: ah i see, maybe this post will help you. i know that it's for symfony2 but with a little modification i could also be used for symfony4. https://riptutorial.com/symfony2/example/22708/add-user-s-details-and-posted-parameters-sent-to-logs